# Scroll to top a div generated by an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have an event calendar with a div on its side.

When I pass the mouse over a day which has some events, those are shown inside the div, the details of the events are retrieved from the db using AJAX.

I had the problem that if I had a day selected, then I scrolled down the div containing the events, then I passed the mouse over another day, the scrollbar stayed down.

To correct this I've used the scrollTop(0) to the div and apparently it did work, but it does only if the new content has the same height or is shorter than the previous, otherwise, if it is longer, the scrollbar returns on top relatively to the old 0, not the new one.

Let's say that I have a content with an height of 800px, I scroll down, then I pass over another day which generates a content of 1000px, the `scrollTop(0)` takes the scrollbar to 200px, not to 0px because I suppose it remembers the old height.

When I have to change the content of the div, I've also tried to change it to the empty string thinking to a kind of reset and then to the actual content, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I've found the problem, it was because of a jQuery plugin to style the scrollbar.